# Styling in WPF is not being applied automatically

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a simple style that I'm trying to apply to all of the buttons in my app:

```
  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundBrush">
    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1" />
  </LinearGradientBrush>
  <SolidColorBrush Color="Purple" x:Key="ButtonForegroundBrush" />
  <SolidColorBrush Color="LimeGreen" x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush" />
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
  </Style>
```

I have this in my app.xaml file, so it is available to everything in my app.  If I put a button on a page, the styles does not apply.  If I add an "x:key" to the style and then add that style name to the button, the style is applied.  Therefore, I know the style is written correctly and is within scope of the button.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why the style does not automatically apply to the buttons as it should if I leave off the x:key from the style?

Comment: Maybe a more local style is taking precedence?

Comment: I have added your style to the Application resources in a new WPF project and the style is applied automatically to the buttons in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Must have been a VS2010 glitch.  I added a new page, put styles in the app.xaml file and they applied to the controls on the new page.  Opened up the old page and, as if by Microsoft magic, the styles started applying.  Truly strange.